# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class OAuthException in /usr/share/php/OAuth.php on line 8

Tags: php

I've got a Debian web server running Squeeze. I will be updating in the coming months but in the meantime I'm getting an error:

`Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class OAuthException in /usr/share/php/OAuth.php on line 8`

The error is a result of installing a WordPress module that uses the same classes as the file at /usr/share/php/OAuth.php. In an effort to fix the issue, I tried wrapping all the classes in the file like this:

`if (!class_exists('OAuthException', false)) {
...
}`

But after doing that I got another error:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PUBLIC in /usr/share/php/OAuth.php on line 786`

I'm not a php developer and so I didn't want to mess with this anymore and so reverted all my changes.

What's the proper fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

If you use this library with OAuth included in PHP you get the following error:

PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class OAuthException in OAuth.php on line 8

Please wrap it like that:

```
if (!class_exists('OAuthException')) { 

    class OAuthException extends Exception {
          // pass
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to remove the files in /user/share/php, find out with apt which module these files belong to and remove them